# Where are the DirectX headers?

Tags: c++, directx, codeblocks

I installed the SDK but I can't seem to find the headers. Where are they? I'm using Code Blocks.

Comment: Peter O. Removed my thanks!

Comment: in the include directory in the sdk.

Comment: try following this tutorial: http://demochronicles.mccolm.org/build.php?mode=nextPage&article=6

Comment: @AlexLarsen: Because Stack Overflow is a Q&A, not a "chat" or discussion forum. Question, answers. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to where you installed the SDK, all of the header files will be in the "Include" directory.

[image]